# Laravel save() if relation already exist

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm currently using the `save()` feature ([doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method)) so save a child item to a parent. But the case where the child is already attached to the parent is not handled.

So I have created this:

```
//Validation stuff

$parent = Task::find( request('parent') );
$child = Task::find( request('child') );

if ( \DB::table('task_has_predecessors')
            ->where('child_id', request('child'))
            ->where('parent_id' , request('parent'))
            ->count() == 0 )
{
    if ( $parent->childs()->save($child) ) 
    {
        flash('Link saved.');
    } 
    else 
    {
        flash()->error('Unable to create the link.');
    } 
}
else
{
    flash()->warning('This link already exist.');
}
```

But I'm not a big fan of this solution... Is there a better way to achieve this without using `if ( \DB::table('...')->where(...)->where(...)->count() == 0 )`?

Has laravel a magic way to manage this kind of behaviour?

---

I don't have any model related to the `tasks_has_predecessors` table.
And my relationships are made like this:

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ChecklistCategoryTask::class, 'task_has_predecessors',  'parent_id','child_id');
    }

    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ChecklistCategoryTask::class, 'task_has_predecessors' , 'child_id' , 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to attach one model to another, use the `attach()` method instead of save and ID instead of an object:

```
$parent->childs()->attach($child->id);
```

And if you're trying to create a new object, use `findOrNew()` instead of `find()`:

```
$child = Task::findOrNew(request('child'));
```

This method will create a new object if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I tried your solution but I still have an `Integrity violation` by using the `attach()` method. I think that I did not formulate my question correctly, so I modified my post

Comment: @Raccoon sounds like you haven't defined relationships correctly.

Comment: I added my relationship definition, Could you take a look?

Comment: @Raccoon the relationships are fine. Then you're using the wrong ID with attach. Make sure you're passing ID of the existing object and also make sure it's ID and not an object.

Comment: I'm sure, I `dd()` the request and yes I have the good ID's. Are you sure that `attach()` manage the case where the relation already exist? I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: @Raccoon no, attach is only for a new relationship. What exactly do you want to do when the relationship exists?

Comment: Flash an error, like explained in the post. I was searching of a more "handy" solution than using `\DB::table('...')->where(...)->where(...)->count() == 0`

Answer (score -1):

See [Belongs To Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method)

From doc

```
$account = App\Account::find(10);
$user->account()->associate($account);
$user->save();
```